# PowerAutomate - replace nth occurrence of character

Tags: power-automate

I'm attempting to parse email body to excel file.
After some manipulations, my current output is an array, where each line is data related to a product.

```
[   
"Periods: 01.01.2023 - 01.02.2023 | Code: 111 | Code2: 1111 | product-name",   
"Periods: 01.01.2023 - 01.02.2023 | Code: 222 | Code2: 2222 | product-name2"
]
```

I need to replace the 3rd occurrence of `" | "` with `" | Product: "` , so i can get field Product before the product name.

I've tried to use Apply to each -> current item -> various ways to find 3rd occurrence and replace it, but can't succeed.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to loop through each item and perform a simple replace expression like thus ...

```
replace(item(), split(item(), ' | ')[3], concat('Product: ', split(item(), ' | ')[3]))
```

That should get you across the line.  Of course, I'm basing my answer off the limited information you provided.

[image: Result]

Comment: "Product-name" was just a dummy, in actual data there is no "Product-" part, hence only viable option i think is to find the 3rd " | " and replace it

Comment: You need to provide a proper example then.

Comment: I specifically wrote what I'm looking for. Anyhow, thank you for the help.

Comment: No, you’ve preempted the answer without providing enough information for an expert to help you. Look at the split function. It will help you.

Comment: I've changed my answer.  Hopefully that works for you now.